# What determines the current consumption in LEDs?

Tags: led, oled

I analyzed some data obtained for some experimental LEDs, and I have asked myself why in some LEDs, the current and current density is higher than others.

Obviously, I am using different materials with different thicknesses in these experiments, which is one reason. Nevertheless, I wanted to analyze by taking the hole mobility in one of my tests. One of my LEDs has lower charge mobility, and as a result, the current and current density is higher than the other LED model.

My theory is that due to the lower charge mobility, the holes and electrons move slower to inside the LED, but they recombine effectively once they achieve the recombination layer. That is one of my arguments, but more points of view are more than welcome, if anyone has any different opinions.

Comment: You tagged the question with led as well as oled. What is it in your case? I don't know anything about the topic, but I assume the physics differ for both technologies.